# Using list comprehension to make lambda functions in Python

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I have a class that initiates as:

```
MorrisLecarElectricField(external_field=lambda t:0, soma_current=lambda t:0, dend_current=lambda t:0, p=0.5, dt=0.1)
```

However, if I want to instantiate a bunch of these like such:

```
neurons = [MLEF.MorrisLecarElectricField(soma_current=lambda t: e) for e in np.arange(0, 200, 10)]
```

some funky pass by reference seems to be happening.  I end up with a list of MorrisLecarElectricField objects that all have soma_current of lambda t: 190.

From what I understand lambdas do something funky with remembering the scope they were created in.  Anybody have any idea how to sidestep this issue?

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions that it is a scoping issue.  However, I'd still like to see if there are solutions that preserve the way I'm instantiating. EDIT: Nevermind, I see that default parameters solves it.

Comment: As answered in the linked question, you force the scope to resolve at declaration by using a default parameter, e.g. `soma_current=lambda t=e: t`.

Comment: Yep, thanks!  Just to clarify my intentions, in this case, it would be actually be  `soma_current=lambda t, e=e: e` since the real motivation is eventually to pass more complicated inputs like `soma_current=lambda t, e=e: e*np.sin(t)`

Comment: You would create a default parameter for any variable that you'd like to see resolved when the function is created rather than when the function is called.